# SharePoint: Trigger workflow only when field is blank

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am looking for a way in SharePoint Designer to trigger a workflow only if a field is blank. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You shoud start workflow every time list item is created or modified and then check value of the field in the workflow. If it is blank - perform some action, otherwise just end workflow